# Remove Sharing Buttons

Tags: html, css, url, iframe, embed

A Sharing Buttons appearing on the right side, when i embed this code. How to Remove it or Disable it?

```
<iframe src='https://my.mail.ru/video/embed/35458859153753045' width='626' height='367' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unless that service you are using there offers any possibility to specify that via an extra parameter, you simply - DON’T. You can not access the iframe content via JS or CSS, since it is loaded from a different origin.

Answer (score 0):

The src of iframe has to be under the same domain. This is due to security reasons. If it is not your domain then you can not do such a thing. But if it is your domain you could always use: `$("#iFrame").contents().find("#Div").remove();`